# Latex - how align to same row these elements

Tags: tables, overleaf

I have developed the following code, but I need to modify it a little bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}

\centerline{\textbf{First}}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
    \nu_1 &= y_1 \\
    \nu_2 &= y_2 \\
    \nu_3 &= \nu_1 \nu_2\\
    \nu_4 &= \ln(\nu_1)\\
    \nu_5 &= \nu_4+\nu_3
\end{split}
\end{align}
\columnbreak

\centerline{\textbf{Second}}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
    \nu_5 &= 1 \\
    \nu_4 &= \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_4}  \\
    \nu_3 &= \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_3}  \\
    \nu_2 &= \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_2} \\
    \nu_1 &= \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_1}\\
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

That's the output of the code:
[image]

1. How can I align each single $\nu_i$? (e.g. the left $\nu_1$ with the right $\nu_5$ to same line, the same for second and so on..)
2. Is possible to add at the end of the picture, something like: "Figure 1" instead having the number of equation (1) and (2) ?

I am goint to attach a picture of what I am interested..

[image]

Comment: You don't need to use `split` in an `align` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `tabularx` and some `\vphantom`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X!{\vrule width 1pt}X@{}}
\centerline{\textbf{First}}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \nu_1 &= y_1 \\
    \nu_2 &= y_2\vphantom{ \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_4}} \\
    \nu_3 &= \nu_1 \nu_2\vphantom{ \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_4}} \\
    \nu_4 &= \ln(\nu_1)\vphantom{ \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_4}} \\
    \nu_5 &= \nu_4+\nu_3\vphantom{ \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_4}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation} &
\centerline{\textbf{Second}}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \nu_5 &= 1 \\
    \nu_4 &= \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_4} \\
    \nu_3 &= \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_3} \\
    \nu_2 &= \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_2} \\
    \nu_1 &= \frac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_1}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If `multicol` is not necessary...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{black}}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{r@{\,}l@{\hspace{1cm}}|@{\hspace{1cm}}r@{\,}l}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\text{\textbf{First}}}
&
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\text{\textbf{Second}}}\\[12pt]
    \nu_1 &= y_1 &    \nu_5 &= 1 \\[6pt]
      \nu_2 &= y_2 &    \nu_4 &= \dfrac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_4} \\[9pt]
     \nu_3 &= \nu_1 \nu_2 &         \nu_3 &= \dfrac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_3}  \\[9pt]
    \nu_4 &= \ln(\nu_1) &    \nu_2 &= \dfrac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_2} \\[9pt]
   \nu_5 &= \nu_4+\nu_3 &         \nu_1 &= \dfrac{\partial \nu_5}{\partial \nu_1}
   \end{array}   
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add label Figure 1 for example using the environment `figure`.